# javascript match defined values in all objects and return rest of values in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, match

I need solution not using any frameworks, just plain javascript.

I have initial values that I need to search in array items:

```
var name = 'blah';
var click = 'double';
```

I have array like this:

```
var items =
[
    {
        name: 'blah',
        click: 'single',
        url: 'url1',
        token: 'token1'
    },
    {
        name: 'blah',
        click: 'double',
        url: 'url2',
        token: 'token2'
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        click: 'double',
        url: 'url3',
        token: 'token3',
    },
    {
        name: 'baz',
        click: 'single',
        url: 'url4',
        token: 'token4'
    }
];
```

When I find the object that contains both values, in this case:

```
{
    name: 'blah',
    click: 'double',
    url: 'url2',
    token: 'token2'
}
```

Than, I need to assign rest of values from that object to separate variables. In this case result should be:

```
var url = 'url2';
var token = 'token2'
```

The problem is that i don't know what the search values will be each time. For example on each button press, search values will be different. Different value for "name" and different value for "click".

I just want to check if it is the same across all objects in that array and assign rest of values to variables.

**UPDATE:**

I was thinking maybe to first create array of found objects that contain matched value from "var name = blah"

```
var names = items.filter(function(item) {return item.name === 'blah'});
```

and then search over "names" array to find what is matching to var click = "double".

```
var match = names.filter(function(matchitem) {return matchitem.click === "double"});
```

Comment: If you don't know what the keyValues are, how can you declare variables to assign the values to?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding I was thinking I don't know on each button press, what will be values of variables I need to search for. I will correct the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which is a method on the `Array` prototype. It would work like this

```
var match = items.find(function(item) {
  return item.name === name && item.click === click;
}
```

Or written in a more modern way

```
const match = items.find(item => item.name === name && item.click === click);
```

Now if you have a match you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it like below to get separate variables for the various properties.

```
const { url, token } = match;
```

The variable names need to match the keys of your object for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first matching object which contains both `name` and `click`

```
const item = items.find(item => item.name === name && item.click === click);
if (item){
  url = item.url;
  token  = item.token;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if something is desired maybe so.

```js
var items = [
  {
    name: 'blah',
    click: 'single',
    url: 'url1',
    token: 'token1'
  },
  {
    name: 'blah',
    click: 'double',
    url: 'url2',
    token: 'token2'
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    click: 'double',
    url: 'url3',
    token: 'token3',
  },
  {
    name: 'baz',
    click: 'single',
    url: 'url4',
    token: 'token4'
  }
];
var name = 'blah';
var click = 'double';

items.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.name == name && item.click == click){
    console.log(item)
  }
})
```

so you have access to the item and everything.

Comment: good answer but I'm not sure how much processing power it takes forEach + if